# posting on communities

Tags: community, socialpost

We were using customized community pages. For posting we have a rich text area and when we post , the email generated(email digest) comes up with html tags instead of formatted text. is there any way to prevent this.
MarkupBegin and MarkupEnd - can this help anyway?

Comment: for sending email what you are using? if you are using single email messaging you need to HTMLbody